# Static Class variable for Thread Count in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, static, static-members

I am writing a thread based application in C++. The following is sample code showing how I am checking the thread count. I need to ensure that at any point in time, there are only 20 worker threads spawned from my application:

```
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
class ThreadWorkerClass
{
  private:
    static int threadCount;
  public:
    void ThreadWorkerClass()
    {
      threadCount ++;
    }
    static int getThreadCount()
    {
      return threadCount;
    }
    void run()
    {
      /* The worker thread execution
       * logic is to be written here */
      //Reduce count by 1 as worker thread would finish here
      threadCount --;
    }
}

int main()
{
  while(1)
  {
    ThreadWorkerClass twObj;
    //Use Boost to start Worker Thread
    //Assume max 20 worker threads need to be spawned
    if(ThreadWorkerClass::getThreadCount() <= 20) 
      boost::thread *wrkrThread = new boost::thread(
        &ThreadWorkerClass::run,&twObj);
    else
      break;
  }
  //Wait for the threads to join
  //Something like (*wrkrThread).join();
  return 0;
}
```

Will this design require me to take a lock on the variable `threadCount`? Assume that I will be running this code in a multi-processor environment.

Comment: void ThreadWorkerClass() => Is this supposed to be the constructor? Then you are creating only a single object and the thread count would never exceed 1.

Comment: Why not just create 20 threads in a `for` loop and leave it at that?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, that is a second approach that I am also considering, in addition to this design. Something like having a constant ThreadPool, and a common queue where tasks/jobs will be submitted.

Comment: @AakashRoy - and David's comment/answer is the best one.  If you can avoid thread micro-management, you should definitely do so.  If you cannot avoid thread micro-management, change your design until you can <g>

Comment: I have also done some more detailed discussion on this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329386/threadpool-using-asio-threads-exit-task-not-performed that is related with this question and my research. Accepted @Moataz's answer as deemed fit for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design is not good enough. The problem is that you exposed the constructor, so whether you like it or not, people will be able to create as many instances of your object as they want. You should do some sort of threads pooling. i.e. You have a class maintaining a set of pools and it gives out threads if available. something like

```
class MyThreadClass {
   public:
      release(){
        //the method obtaining that thread is reponsible for returning it
      }
};

class ThreadPool {
  //create 20 instances of your Threadclass
  public:
  //This is a blocking function
  MyThreadClass getInstance() {
     //if a thread from the pool is free give it, else wait
  }
};
```

So everything is maintaned internally by the pooling class. Never give control over that class to the others. you can also add query functions to the pooling class, like hasFreeThreads(), numFreeThreads() etc...

You can also enhance this design through giving out smart pointer so you can follow how many people are still owning the thread. 
Making the people obtaining the thread responsible for releasing it is sometimes dangerous, as processes crashes and they never give the tread back, there are many solutions to that, the simplest one is to maintain a clock on each thread, when time runs out the thread is taken back by force.